# FieldOptional FileHelpers Must be Marked as Optional Because the Previous Field is Marked as Optional

Tags: c#, .net, filehelpers

I am using filehelpers 2.9.9 and trying to use FiledOptional but I keep getting this error

> The field: SystemUrl must be marked as optional because the previous field is marked as optional. (Try adding [FieldOptional] to SystemUrl)

SystemUrl is the first field and I marked it FieldOptional. Does every other field after it need to marked as Optional Too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SystemUrl is the first field and I marked it FieldOptional. Does every other field after it need to marked as Optional Too?

Yes.  Once you mark a field as optional, all subsequent fields must also be optional.

If you don't want this behavior, you'll need to move `SystemUrl` to the end, not have it first.

Comment: Kinda weird behavior that it forces to make other things optional when you do not want it to be. It would be nice if they stated that in the documentation. How about if you use FieldOrder do you have to drop that as well?

Comment: @chobo2 Not sure - but it requires optional values to all be last, as that way it can properly parse when things are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is about what FieldOptional do: it must be used for fields that can be or not in the file, them must be at the end of the record class, if you have 3 fields Field1, Field2 and Field3 (all strings) and you have

```
stringA,stringB,stringC
```

later you set Field2 as optional, with that the library can parse:

```
stringA,stringB
```

Because can't disambiguate it.

Can you provide a sample record ? maybe you need FieldNotInFile instead of optional if you don't want to processes that field.